# Apk downloaded from playstore and release dashboard gives different hash

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

I am getting old bugs on my app which were already fixed in previous builds, the weird thing is these bugs only occurs when I download my app from the playstore. The app works without any bug or crash when I download the apk from my playconsole release dashboard or internal test(I tried both the original and modified download option). All of the apks are the exact same build version.

I have already tried to check the hash of the apks by doing the following:

1. Download apk from internal test dashboard (modified version)
2. Download apk from release dashboard (modified and original versions)
3. Download the app from playstore then get apk via adb

Then I generate hash using the command

```
openssl dgst -md5 appname.apk
```

and got same hash for apks from 1 and 2. However, for 3 the hash is different and it's also the only apk with all the bugs that were already fixed. I am not sure what causes this and I don't know it normally the hash from store and release dashboard are normally different. Thankyou for any help.

Answer (score 0):

When you upload your app on play console, its again  re-signed apk using `PEPK tool` for security. That's why you get different `SHA-1` key from play console.

You can get more information from this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing)

You'll get setps for getting this `SHA-1` back from your play console. Download `PEPK.jar` from your console & get SHA-1 key via `cmd`.

This will help you. see this [command](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi1.wp.com%2Fblog.fossasia.org%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F08%2Fscreenshot_20170822_204951-750x586.png%3Fresize%3D750%252C586&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.fossasia.org%2Fenabling-google-app-signing-for-android-project%2F&docid=AGJaZkfXHi8C_M&tbnid=H5V8rM3FSLfnSM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwi7q-n7lLbhAhXJb30KHeWiCncQMwhOKAswCw..i&w=750&h=586&bih=757&biw=1440&q=get%20sha-1%20key%20from%20pepk%20tool%20in%20andorid&ved=0ahUKEwi7q-n7lLbhAhXJb30KHeWiCncQMwhOKAswCw&iact=mrc&uact=8)

Comment: In the Play Console, under Release Management > Artifact Library, you can download an "Original version" and a "Derived version". From my understanding, the original version should be signed with the upload key, whereas the Derived version should be re-signed. Hence the version on the Play Store should have the same SHA-1 key as the Derived Version, no? See screenshot here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g4aaka6ixqwnskc/Screenshot%202019-04-05%2011.00.25.png?dl=0